# Subdirectory not created with proper group even parent has SGID

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a folder with the SGID bit on:

```
lucas@arturito:/home$ ls -l | grep share
drwxrwsr-x 11 share      sambashare  4096 May  5 14:54 share
```

If I move into share an I create a folder within it, that folder will have the group 'sambashare'. So far, so good...

```
lucas@arturito:/home$ cd share/
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ mkdir test
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ ls -l | grep test
drwxrwsr-x  2 lucas sambashare 4096 May  5 15:07 test
```

Now, if I move under /home/share/test and create a new folder, that new folder inherits the group: SGID is working.

```
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ cd test
lucas@arturito:/home/share/test$ mkdir test1
lucas@arturito:/home/share/test$ ls -l | grep test1
drwxrwsr-x 2 lucas sambashare 4096 May  5 15:09 test1
```

However, under /home/share I do have other folders other than the newly created 'test'. If I move under any of those, and create a new folder (say 'test2'), that new folder will ignore the SGID and the group will be my group.

```
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ ls -l | grep 99
drwxrwxr-x  9 share sambashare 4096 May  5 15:11 99_varios

lucas@arturito:/home/share$ cd 99_varios/
lucas@arturito:/home/share/99_varios$ mkdir test2
lucas@arturito:/home/share/99_varios$ ls -l | grep test2
drwxrwxr-x  2 lucas lucas      4096 May  5 15:11 test2
```

Why is that happening? Isn't it enough for /home/share to have g+s for *any* other directory below it (new or old) to inherit /home/share's group?

I'm lost. Any hint or idea will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New folders will inherit the bit but existing ones need to have it set explicitly. You can run the command below once to recursively set it on any existing subfolders.

```
find /home/share -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfred, that indeed is the answer: I though *any* folder would inherit the SGID. Now that I've recursively set it on all the subfolders, everything is working as expected. Thanks! Lucas